# The Lebesgue Decomposition of Lebesgue-Stieltjes Measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Explanations about this question:

Let $\begin{equation}
g(x)=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{x<0}\\
x+2& \text{x>=0}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}$ ,then $v$ is a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure induced by $g(x)$,So here comes the question:How to calculate the Lebesgue decomposition of $v$ related to the Lebesgue measure $m$

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no explicit way to construct a decomposition in a general way… a good start is to check the absolutely continuous part of the function and the set of discontinuities because in the absolutely continuous set area we can calculate a Lebesgue-density and for discontinuities we can use the dirac-measure at that point... unfortunately there are functions which are neither absolutely continuous nor have jumps for some points.

But for your example we have: $g$ is absolutely continuous on $(0,\infty)$ with $\frac{dg}{dx} = 1$ and has a jump of height $2$ at $0$ hence we have for the induced measure $\lambda_g = \lambda_{(0,\infty)} + 2\delta_0$ where $\lambda_{(0,\infty)}$ denotes the lebesgue measure on $(0,\infty)$ and $\delta_0$ the dirac measure at $0$. Because the decomposition is unique we found the Lebesgue decomposition.

Comment: Thanks a lot,you really hit the point.But I found some mistakes.Well,the right answer should be $\lambda_g=\chi_{(0,+\infty)}\lambda+2\delta_0$,otherwise you will find that $3=g(1)-g(-1)=\lambda_g((-1,1])=\lambda((-1,1])+2=4$

Comment: Hey… yeah ofc… just forgot the index at $\lambda$. Added.