# Lebesgue decomposition of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a similar question as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2595236/the-lebesgue-decomposition-of-lebesgue-stieltjes-measure?rq=1).

Lesbesgue-Stieltjes measure $\mu_F$ with the function $F=\lvert x\rvert\lfloor x\rfloor$. i.e. $\mu_F([a,b))=F(b)-F(a)$. I am trying to find the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition of $\mu_F$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$.

Now, I know this function has countably many discontinuities at each integer-valued $x$, so I believe I want the mutually singular part to be the Dirac Measure of each integer, and take the absolute continuous part to be the Lebesgue measure itself. But it would have to be a countable sum of Dirac measures for the discontinuity points… and I am not sure if I am allowed to do that, or if my approach is ok.

I would love to get some feedback/a point in the right direction or any help in general.

Comment: Each integer is an atom, and its size is $|x|.$ I think there is no diffuse part that is continuous and the absolutely continuous part will be obtained by difference.

Comment: @WillM. What do you mean by "there is no diffuse part"? And do you mean the absolute continuous part with respect to Lebesgue measure is simply difference of $F$ at endpoints, or do you mean something else? Also, wouldn't the atom's size be 1?

Comment: On the one hand, a measure $\mu$ is "diffuse" if $\mu(\mathrm{K}) = 0$ for all finite $\mathrm{K}.$  On the other hand, you will construct a measure $\mu$ that is atomic (the atoms of $\mu_F$) then the absolutely continuous part, my guess is, $\mu_F-\mu.$

Comment: @WillM. I'm not sure if I follow.. If you have the time, do you mind writing out the answer?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It's just the Stieltjes function for the L-S measure: $\mu_F([a,b))=F(b)-F(a)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$It is fine to add countably many measures to define a new measure as long as all of them are non-negative.

For this question, define$$
μ_c(\d x) = |\lfloor x\rfloor| \, m(\d x),\quad μ_s(\d x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |n| δ_n(\d x), 
$$
i.e.$$
μ_c(A) = \int_A |\lfloor x\rfloor| \,\d x,\quad μ_s(A) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |n| I_A(n).
$$
It easy to verify that $μ_c$ and $μ_s$ are indeed measures and $μ_c \ll m$, $μ_s ⊥ m$.

To prove that $μ_F = μ_c + μ_s$, it suffices to prove that for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $k \leqslant a < b \leqslant k + 1$,$$
μ_c((a, b]) + μ_s((a, b]) = μ_F((a, b]).
$$
If $b < k + 1$, note that $ab > 0$, then$$
μ_c((a, b]) + μ_s((a, b]) = |k| (b - a) + 0 = |b| k - |a| k = μ_F((a, b]).
$$
Otherwise, note that $|k| (k + 1) = |k + 1| k$ since $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, then\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} μ_c((a, k + 1]) + μ_s((a, k + 1]) = |k| (k + 1 - a) + |k + 1|\\
&= |k + 1| (k + 1) - |k| a = μ_F((a, b]).
\end{align*}
Therefore, $μ_F = μ_c + μ_s$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do the $dx$'s next to $\mu_c, \mu_s$ mean?

Comment: @Mog Simply a notation as in $μ(A)=\int_Aμ(\mathrm dx)$.